# Send variable to PHP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I'm trying send a js variable to php and make a query with same variable.

When i click on marker i get `Success` on console, but when i try make the query i get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (index):105
(anonymous function) (index):105
request.onreadystatechange (index):185
```

Line 105 `var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);`

Line 185 `callback(request);`(part of makeRequest)

JavaScript:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
    if (start.value.length <=0){
        start.value=data[i].name;
        start_cord.value ="("+(data[i].lat +", "+ data[i].lon)+")";
        xpto = data[i].name;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'get_waypoint.php',
            data: { var1: xpto },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                console.log('Success')
            }
});
```

get_waypoint.php:

```
require 'config.php';
$var = $_POST['var1'];

try {

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sth = $db->query("SELECT distinct * FROM horarios WHERE name ='$var'");
    $locations = $sth->fetchAll();

    echo json_encode( $locations );

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

makeRequest:

```
function makeRequest(url, callback) {
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            callback(request);
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
}
```

**EDIT**

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_waypoint.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {var1:start_wp, var2:end_wp},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
        console.log('Success')

        for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
            waypts.push({location: new google.maps.LatLng(msg[i].lat, msg[i].lon),
            stopover: true})
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you visit the PHP page the JavaScript requests and see if it outputs any errors? You have `$e->getMessage()` in your PHP code. If an error is being displayed, JavaScript won't be able to process that, as it expects JSON. Errors are output in HTML – the error "unexpected <" would thus make sense.

---

Here's another important problem in your code. Instead of the following:

```
$sth = $db->query("SELECT distinct * FROM horarios WHERE name ='$var'");
```

please use

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT distinct * FROM horarios WHERE name =?");
$sth->execute( array($var) );
```

Otherwise, you are prone to SQL injections.

---

**Update:** User said in comments he gets `Notice: Undefined index: var1 in "location"\get_waypoint.php on line 3`

In PHP, replace:

```
$var = $_POST['var1'];
```

with:

```
if(isset($_POST['var1'])) {
    $var = $_POST['var1'];
}
else {
    exit; // Or handle error as you wish
}
```

You are missing a set of quotes in your JavaScript. Replace

```
data: { var1: xpto },
```

to

```
data: { 'var1': xpto },
```

Comment: the erros i see are the ones i posted here. i don´t know if it makes diference but i forgot say the file with js script is `index.html`

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about potential errors in your PHP file, i.e. in get_waypoint.php. It would be good if you could visit the page your Ajax code requests (i.e. `POST get_waypoint.php` with `var1`)

Comment: you mean `Notice: Undefined index: var1 in "location"\get_waypoint.php on line 3`? i get it with Ashok sri code after send variable

Comment: @user3782315 Exactly. JavaScript doesn't understand this as it's JSON. I've updated my answer.

Comment: now i get `Unexpected end of input` u suppose that is output of `exit;`

Comment: @user3782315 You could try outputting a JSON-format error to confirm, or revisit the page manually. In your code, `xpto` is defined as `data[i].name`, so make sure that it contains what you're expecting (e.g. test with `alert()`).

Comment: yes i already have done that and `data[i].name` have the right value.

Comment: proble solved. i was sending variable with ajax and on other function i was calling `makeRequest(waypoint.php)`, to get waypoints. thats why i'm getting error. now i updated ajax (edited on Question) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would clarify exactly what data is being returned from your PHP. Your PHP script has two endpoints; returning a JSON encoded data set, or returning a PHP error messsage string. The latter will not be JSON encoded, and therefore when your browser executes the JSON.parse method, it falls over because it isn't in the expected format. I therefore advise walking through the PHP and checking if it enters the 'catch' block. The reason for this would likely be database related.

If you can confirm that it does not enter the 'catch' block, by successfully print_r'ing the $locations variable, and checking the output of $locations, it may contain characters that corrupt your JSON. The json_encoding function has numerous flags that you can pass to it, which enable the function to parse particular character sets. The following call would enable all possible flags:

`json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Answer (score 0):

try below code,

```
function yourfunction(value)
 {

if (value=="")
 {
 document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML="";
 return;
 }
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {

    document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

  }
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getclientip_graph1.php?var1="+value,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```